# How to assign variable names within a stage containing build job info to use in another stage's build job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to have a single job start a bunch of others job using pipeline. The issue I am facing is that the other jobs require job info from sibling and upstream jobs. Here is what I have so far:

```
def x = ""
def y = ""
def i = ""
def q = ""
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage(...){
            parallel {
                stage(...) {
                    steps {
                        build job1
                        **x = <grab job1's name>
                        y = <grab job1's build number>**
                    }
                }
                stage(...) {
                    steps {
                        build job2 **USING job1's name and build number as parameters** in x and y
                        i = <grab job2's name for later>
                        q = <grab job2's build number for later>
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible? What is the best way to do this?

See above code for reference into what I tried.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the job name in advance in order to trigger a job, but you can get the job number from the result of `build` step:

```
    final job_result = build job: 'SomeJobName', parameters: [...], wait: true // etc.
    def job_number = job_result.number
```

So in your case

```
                        x = "Well-known job name"
                        def job_result = build job: x 
                        y = job_result.number
```